# how to make a field can not be filled minus or symbol?

Tags: php, html, regex, verification

So like normal field input, This filed should be filled only by numbers or letters, can not insert like symbol(~!@#$/%^&-+=|*.\,) and minus numbers in PHP/html. Can help me please? i done search in internet not found only found for sql or vb

```
<input type="text" name="text" value="">
```

where this field will be POST to another php
$name =trim($_POST['name']);

Comment: look into regex, namely preg_replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php):

```
bool ctype_alnum ( string $text )
```

Comment: Thx for ur comment i know now :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use [alnum](https://github.com/Respect/Validation#valnum) method of [respect/validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation):

```
if(v::alnum()->validate($stringToCheck)){
  //valid
}
else {
  //not valid
}
```